# Angular Date filter extend - translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Hi while developing an application that give the user the option to pick a date i faced a problem with the translations of date filter, i came up with this solution:

- Extend the date filter
- Replace the months and days of the week by another values
- The values where defined on a .json file

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/eralha/angular-date-translations

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, if anyone have sugestions i will apperciate.